# Error in running Python scripts

Tags: python

I have python 2.7 installed and I'm facing errors while trying to run scripts in Python. The GUI based Launchpad app Ground Control can't start and is facing bugs.

But even a simple program can't run:

```
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen

pg = urlopen("http://www.beans-r-us.biz/proces.html")

text = pg.read().decode("utf8")
where = text.find(">$")
start_of_price = where + 2
end_og_price = start_og_price + 4
price = float(text[start_of_price:end_of_price])

print "The current price of coffee is:", price
```

The error log is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "androidscript.py", line 4, in <module>
    pg = urlopen("http://www.beans-r-us.biz/proces.html")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 432, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 619, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
anant@anant-Inspiron-N5010:~/Documents$
```

Someone please help me out with it.

Comment: We can only comment on your sample script. Obviously the URL you gave it does not exist (Error 404). Try with: `http://beans.itcarlow.ie/prices.html`

Comment: You have many typos. `end_og_price`, `proces` etc.

Comment: The link solves my problem. Thanks, and sorry for my stupidity.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one that works:

```
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen
try:
    #pg = urlopen("http://www.beans-r-us.biz/proces.html")
    pg = urlopen("http://beans.itcarlow.ie/prices.html")
except:
    pg = False
#if pg!=False:    
if pg:    
    text = pg.read().decode("utf8")
    where = text.find(">$")
    start_of_price = where + 2
    end_of_price = start_of_price + 4
    try:
        price = float(text[start_of_price:end_of_price])
    except:
        price = 'unknown.  Some error happened parsing the price...'
else:
    price = 'unknown.  Some error happened while getting the url...'
print "The current price of coffee is:", price
```

Slight improvement in that it handles the invalid URL a bit more gracefully...although not descriptively.

edit: change pg!=False to pg credit to [Jo](https://askubuntu.com/users/19779/jo-erlend-schinstad).  He's right that it's cleaner.  I thought it might make more sense to someone copy pasting code to see the false spelled out.

Comment: "if something != False:" is unnecessary. It's cleaner to use "if something:", which is the exact same thing to the interpreter. The float conversion should be in a try clause, though. It's highly likely it'll fail at some point. It should be handled properly. Good answer none the less. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely certain that you spelled that address correctly? And that your internet connection is working? Because the error you get is HTTP 404, meaning the resource can't be found -- not some strange python internal error.

Comment: Sorry about the URL not working, I didn't know that. I took it from http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10940?page=0,2

Answer (score 0):

Try This Instead:

```
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen

pg = urlopen("http://www.beans-r-us.biz/prices.html")

text = pg.read().decode("utf8") 
where = text.find('>$') 
start_of_price = where + 2 
end_of_price = start_of_price + 4 
price = float(text[start_of_price:end_of_price])

print "The current price of coffee is:", price
```